# Check Boto3 Version

Tags: python

How do I check the version of boto3 I am running?

I tried going into REPL and running these commands:

```
>>> import boto3
>>> boto3.Version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'boto3' has no attribute 'Version'
```

Comment: Try `.__version__` or `.version`

Comment: `boto3.__version__` is what worked. I got back '1.9.101' as an answer.

Comment: @BHC Might be worth posting your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I know this is late but you can also use:

pip show boto3

Comment: This works, but it outputs much more information than only the version!

Comment: Well, if it outputs much more info, you can just do this:
`pip show boto3 | grep Version`

Comment: Or for just the first entry of Version: ```pip3 show boto3 | grep ^Version```

Comment: To update use this: pip install --upgrade boto3

Answer (score 10):

You can always use dir function to know all the properties and methods of object.

```
dir(boto3)

['DEFAULT_SESSION', 'NullHandler', 'Session', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', '_get_default_session', 'client', 'docs', 'exceptions', 'logging', 'resource', 'resources', 'session', 'set_stream_logger', 'setup_default_session', 'utils']
```

From this output you can see `__version__`.

```
boto3.__version__
```

Answer (score 8):

Try using `.__version__` or `.version`

PEP 8 standard is to use the `__version__` attribute for this, however it is worth noting that some modules implement `version` instead.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to check the version of any installed packages, In the terminal

```sh
pip freeze | grep boto3
```

Note: you can replace boto3 with any other package name